# Display "#" symbol in html?

Tags: php, html

This is driving me nuts - I want to just display a hash symbol (#) in html but it just won't show it.

I've tried `&#35;` but nothing shows.

I want to put it at the start of my title tag like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo $fields->image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $fields->dish_name; ?>" height="160" width="314" title="# <?php echo $fields->dish_number; ?> <?php echo $fields->dish_name; ?>" />
```

Update:
http://www.orientalcatering.co.uk/v1/
This is the page I'm working on, it's the second slider towards the bottom right of the page that I'm trying to get a comment up in (you use the title tag to do this).

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/P8Fsf/1/ (hover over the text)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the following works perfectly fine: `<html><img src="" title="# Stackoverflow!" /></html>`. The hash is shown correctly in IE and in FF when hovering over the broken image. Maybe you can provide a short (PHP-free) example to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&#35;` is the HTML entity for the `#` symbol.

Also you can simplify:

```
<?php echo $fields->dish_number; ?> <?php echo $fields->dish_name; ?>
```

to just:

```
<?php echo $fields->dish_number, $fields->dish_name; ?>
```

After reading your responses to my answer it is clear you have asked the wrong question, you are not having trouble with the `title` attribute per-say but rather you have used it incorrectly in attempting to set up your Nivo Slider.

To add a caption to a Slide in Nivo slider you give it a title that references the id of a div (note the div must have the class `nivo-html-caption`, and be outside of your `img` tag), e.g.

```
<img src="blah.com/blah.png" class="nivoSlider" title="#description1" />
<div id="description1" class="nivo-html-caption">This is your caption</div>
```

The `title` attribute is used mainly for supplementary information about the contents or purpose of an element. In most modern browsers hovering over an image will reveal it's title attribute. This is often taken advantage of in Javascript as you have seen as a way to pass more data, but each script will have it's own method of implementation.

Comment: @Rob Can you post your doctype code? I have a feeling you have an incorrect charset set.

Comment: @Rob Using the `&#35;` works fine for me on that page. Can you insert and point to the error? You also successfully have the `#` character in the titles already...

Comment: On the Nivo above where it says "Celia's Dishes" there should be the dish number and name in the black opaque area. I'm using Chrome and currently nothing shows up.

Comment: @Rob The problem is not with the title tag, it is because you are using the Nivo Slider script incorrectly. The title tag does what it does. I updated my answer with how to set up the Nivo Slider how you want it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the “#” character as data in HTML, any more than about the letter “A.” (And if there were, “#” would not help much, would it, as it contains the “­#” character.)

The problem is rather with the mechanism used to change images. This seems to be somewhat complicated, but it results in hiding an `img` element and using a background image instead. When the `img` element is hidden using `display: none`, its attributes have no effect.

Thus, you need a different mechanism for changing the image (I wonder why a simple JavaScript-driven image changer, directly modifyin the attributes of an `img` element, hasn’t been used), or maybe a tooltip-like mechanism implemented in JavaScript and CSS rather than with simple `title` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Educated guess: You have a ISO-8859-1 encoded pound sign in a UTF-8
>   encoded page.
>
> Make sure your data is in the right encoding and everything will work
>   fine.

[From a Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382518/why-cant-i-display-a-pound-symbol-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `&#35` for a hex symbol.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an error either with php somewhere, or there's some sort of character sanitation happening elsewhere.

I say that because having a # in a title is not a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/T5GyL/

Try just doing a non-php snippet first to see if it really is a problem

Answer (score 0):

These are how you display **"#"** in some ways as shown below:

```
&num; or &#35; or &#x23;
```

In addtion, these are how you display **"♯"** which is different from **"#"** in some ways as shown below:

```
&#x266F; or &#9839; or &sharp;
```