# Can't get pound (£) sign to show in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Very simple scenario, but could not find a fix. How can I get a pound sign (£) to display correctly in all browsers in Classic ASP?

I have the following:

```
<% Response.Write "£pound;" & (number) %>
```

Comment: Which content encoding is used? And shouldn't it be `&pound;` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I display a pound (£) symbol in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382518/why-cant-i-display-a-pound-symbol-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `&pound;` instead of `£pound;`

See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp