# Rails 4: HTML Code Inside Link_to

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

On the output I'd like to have this:

```
<%= link_to '&pound;', '#' %>
```

to show:

```
£
```

I wish not to input "£" as is, I need to input the html code for £. Is there a way?

I'm trying to accomplishe this: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html

Comment: did you try "£".html_safe ? or .h?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382518/why-cant-i-display-a-pound-%C2%A3-symbol-in-html

Comment: @Mingsheng post it as an answer <%= link_to '&pound;'.html_safe, '#' %> as it works

Comment: lol its ok someone posted already. just saw it

Comment: @Mingsheng LOL I thought is was you lol. Never mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work

> ```
> '&pound;'.html_safe
> ```