# Replacing £ character from html textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently developing a simple web app using html with JavaScript, and I'm trying to do a simple string.replace call on a string received from a html textarea like so;

```
var contents = document.getElementById("contents").value;
var alteredText = contents.replace(/£/g, "poundsign");
```

The problem is that when a £ sign is included in the string, the replace call can't find it. I've looked at the code via the console and it seems that anytime there's a $ sign in JavaScript it adds a "Â" to the £ symbol, so

```
string.replace(/£/g, "poundsign");
```

as it was written in the js file becomes the following while running:

```
string.replace(/Â£/g, "poundsign");
```

while £ in var contents remains simply £ (putting Â£ into the textarea causes the replace call to work correctly). Is there a way to stop the Â being added in the js file, or to add it to the html file before .replace is called?

The Â is added anytime £ appears in the js file as far as I can see, and I haven't been able to get it to match up with the html without the user adding the Â to the html themselves.

Comment: string.replace(/£/g, "poundsign"); are you targeting variable var_string.replace ? Also why are you doing "/£/g" why not just "£" ? there's no need to Regex it ?

Comment: Can you check this link out?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes

Comment: possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382518/why-cant-i-display-a-pound-%C2%A3-symbol-in-html

Comment: @Riddell there might be multiple occurrences of "£", so we need to add /g option, and for that we need to use Regex.

Comment: @Mike I see, well thanks for information Mike!

Answer (score 0):

```
   // replace pound string by empty string
   var mystr = '£';
   mystr = mystr.replace(/£/g,'poundsign');
   alert(mystr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David Guan for the link, that put me on the right track, and to everyone else that commented.

The issue was resolved when I used the Unicode number in the .replace call rather than the character, it was able to then match the £ sign correctly without the Â also being inserted.