# Pound Signs appearing as Question Marks PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm having problems with Pound Signs appearing as Question Marks within a diamond in my PHP script which pulls data from a MySQL Database.

I have looked through other Stack Overflow answers and I think checked everything.

I have checked in php.ini that I have default_charset = "utf-8", I have also added AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and to /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/charset.conf

I have also added this to the top of the web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<HEAD>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ZXDB</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
```

Finally I ran sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart to restart the server.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache and PHP7.

What am I missing?

The page is available here:

```
http://spectrumcomputing.co.uk/originalprices.php
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: look in the DB and see what charset it uses for the table, you may have to change it to that charset.

Comment: Hi there.  Just looked at the table and its set as utf8_bin

Comment: That means UTF8 binary

Comment: Should that work OK?

Comment: In theory, if you don't mind case sensitive searches.  Usually seeing a black diamond with a question mark is a charset issue.

Comment: Do you mean the currency pound or the `#` pound sign ... lol ...  this may be helpful   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565801/gbp-pound-symbol-appearing-as-uknown-char-in-shop

Comment: In the database the field is showing as £9.99 in the webpage I get the £ in the black diamond the 9.99

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for their answers.  Even though the database, the table and the field were all set as UTF-8, when I checked the Character set with this:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

It said it was Latin, so I fixed it with adding this to my PHP

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

Where $conn is your connection string

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Is `£` showing up as a *single* `�`?  If so, see "Black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831 .  That says:

Case 1 (original bytes were not UTF-8):

- The bytes to be stored are not encoded as utf8. Fix this.
- The connection (or SET NAMES) for the INSERT and the SELECT was not utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Case 2 (original bytes were UTF-8):

- The connection (or SET NAMES) for the SELECT was not utf8/utf8mb4. Fix this.
- Also, check that the column in the database is CHARACTER SET utf8 (or utf8mb4).

Black diamonds occur only when the browser is set to `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.